# MSBuild .NET project that will output existing assembly as it's result

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, projects-and-solutions

I need to create csproj file that will be usable as project reference in VS2013 and will output prebuilt binary as it's "Build" result.

We use referenced projects for build, however company policy doesn't allow access to some of that projects for everyone. As a result projects need to be updated manually to make them build. This is really a major inconvenience when switching branches and when making edits to project files, so I want to create dummy project that will be bound to pre-built binaries as their "output" and will be placed instead of real projects.

**EDIT:** Moving that assembly to Nuget package is not an option for now since Nuget has some issues with dev flow (when you need to debug/test/develop package). I saw some VS extension that implements switching between Nuget package and local project which might solve this issue, but I'm not sure if it will be accepted and want to explore other options.

To be clear - the thing I want to avoid is editing project in any way, so that project can be built cleanly after pulling it from Git, and I don't have to clean it every time before commit.

Comment: Have you tried using git submodules? Or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: How about adding a pre-build script to your projects which copy the latest versions of the assemblies that are being referenced? Creating a dummy project sounds unnecessary.

Comment: Git submodules are not an option - we _don't have access to that repo_, and that's the problem.
As of pre-build script - it will not switch references from projects (which are referenced in those projects) to built assemblies (which we need to use).

Comment: Well, actually project dependencies resolution (combined with security policy) is the worst issue on my current project, so it's not that bad. And we're trying to implement some proper workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't properly tested it, but the solution seems really simple (if I understand the question properly).

Just add this to the existing .csproj, overriding the Build target to just give the path to the pre-built assembly.

```
  <Target
      Name="Build"
      Returns="$(TargetPath)" />
```

This assumes the `TargetPath` property already defined, and it should automatically be if you're modifying the original .csproj. Otherwise just define it yourself in a `<PropertyGroup>` before the Build task.

Note that having `TargetPath` defined is important for the `ProjectReference`s in your own project to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

How about having those restricted (binary only) projects reside in an internal Nuget package feed, so that Nuget can install the packages as needed, on build?

Comment: Well, I proposed it. That's not an option because nuget has issues with dev flow - we need only to use core assembly, but other devs need to debug and develop it. I saw some extension that allows switching between nuget packages and projects, we'll see how it goes. But for now I need some other solution.